# Javascript echo for each an array while also converting from string to int

Tags: javascript

I have an array with two values, my goal is to take the roman numerals, convert them into integers, then outputting them one by one using for each. My issue is in my roman numeral function converter, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: str1.charAt is not a function on line 16` which is the code `var num = char_to_int(str1.charAt(0));`

```
var dynastyReign = [ 
  {"One Dynasty": "MXLI"},
  {"Two Dynasty": "MCCCIIII"},
  {"Three Dynasty": "MCCCXCVIII"},  
  {"Four Dynasty": "MCDXLV"},   
  {"Five Dynasty": "MDCLXIV"}, 
  {"Six Dynasty": "MCMXLIX"},
  {"Seven Dynasty": "MMMXICX"}
];

function roman_to_Int(str1) {
if(str1 == null) return -1;
var num = char_to_int(str1.charAt(0));
var pre, curr;

for(var i = 1; i < str1.length; i++){
curr = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i));
pre = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i-1));
if(curr <= pre){
num += curr;
} else {
num = num - pre*2 + curr;
}
}

return num;
}

function char_to_int(c){
switch (c){
case 'I': return 1;
case 'V': return 5;
case 'X': return 10;
case 'L': return 50;
case 'C': return 100;
case 'D': return 500;
case 'M': return 1000;
default: return -1;
}
}

var year = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);

dynastyReign.forEach(function(year) {
document.write(roman_to_Int(year));
});
```

How I made my code is first, to create a converter function from roman numbers to int, declare a variable to only get the roman number portion of the array (var year), then using for each to output the integer along with the converter `roman_to_Int(year)`. I am not sure which part should i fix, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You construct an array of the roman years with

```
var year = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);
```

but then you proceed to iterate over the `dynastyReign` array instead, and it's an array of objects, so

```
var romanYears = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);
romanYears.forEach(function(year) {
  document.write(roman_to_Int(year));
});
```

throws because `roman_to_Int` accepts a string, not an object.

Iterate over the roman years instead (and add a newline between the outputs to make things readable):

```
romanYears.forEach(function(year) {
  document.write(roman_to_Int(year) + '<br>');
});
```

```js
var dynastyReign = [{
    "One Dynasty": "MXLI"
  },
  {
    "Two Dynasty": "MCCCIIII"
  },
  {
    "Three Dynasty": "MCCCXCVIII"
  },
  {
    "Four Dynasty": "MCDXLV"
  },
  {
    "Five Dynasty": "MDCLXIV"
  },
  {
    "Six Dynasty": "MCMXLIX"
  },
  {
    "Seven Dynasty": "MMMXICX"
  }
];

function roman_to_Int(str1) {
  if (str1 == null) return -1;
  var num = char_to_int(str1.charAt(0));
  var pre, curr;

  for (var i = 1; i < str1.length; i++) {
    curr = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i));
    pre = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i - 1));
    if (curr <= pre) {
      num += curr;
    } else {
      num = num - pre * 2 + curr;
    }
  }

  return num;
}

function char_to_int(c) {
  switch (c) {
    case 'I':
      return 1;
    case 'V':
      return 5;
    case 'X':
      return 10;
    case 'L':
      return 50;
    case 'C':
      return 100;
    case 'D':
      return 500;
    case 'M':
      return 1000;
    default:
      return -1;
  }
}

var romanYears = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);

romanYears.forEach(function(year) {
  document.write(roman_to_Int(year) + '<br>');
});
```

Could also clean up the code a lot, including avoiding `document.write` (which there's not really any good reason to use nowadays) and using an object instead of `switch`:

```js
var dynastyReign=[{"One Dynasty":"MXLI"},{"Two Dynasty":"MCCCIIII"},{"Three Dynasty":"MCCCXCVIII"},{"Four Dynasty":"MCDXLV"},{"Five Dynasty":"MDCLXIV"},{"Six Dynasty":"MCMXLIX"},{"Seven Dynasty":"MMMXICX"}];

const romanCharacterMap = {
  I: 1,
  V: 5,
  X: 10,
  L: 50,
  C: 100,
  D: 500,
  M: 1000
};

function romanToInt(str1) {
  let num = char_to_int(str1[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < str1.length; i++) {
    const curr = char_to_int(str1[i]);
    const pre = char_to_int(str1[i - 1]);
    if (curr <= pre) {
      num += curr;
    } else {
      num = num - pre * 2 + curr;
    }
  }
  return num;
}

const char_to_int = c => romanCharacterMap[c];

var romanYears = dynastyReign.map(d => Object.values(d)[0]);

romanYears.forEach(function(year) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = romanToInt(year);
});
```